# Java прорисовка под MAC OS на разных версиях jdk

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день. Есть класс, который рисует тень. Под виндовсом все хорошо, но в MAC OS в java 6 рисует как надо, а java 7 и 8 рисует неправильно. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо заранее.

```java
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestFrame();
  }

  public TestFrame() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);


    DropShadowPanel panel = new DropShadowPanel(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.3f), 25, 0);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


public class DropShadowPanel extends JPanel {

  private static Color shadowColor;
  private static int shadowSize;
  private static int shadowDistance;

  public DropShadowPanel() {
    this(Color.black);
  }

  public DropShadowPanel(Color shadowColor) {
    this(shadowColor, 25);
  }

  public DropShadowPanel(Color shadowColor, int shadowSize) {
    this(shadowColor, shadowSize, 0);
  }

  public DropShadowPanel(Color shadowColor, int shadowSize, int shadowDistance) {
    this.shadowColor = shadowColor;
    this.shadowSize = shadowSize;
    this.shadowDistance = shadowDistance;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;


    Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(25, 25, 300, 300);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fill(r);
    if (shadowSize > 0) {
      draw(g, r, shadowSize);
    }
  }

  private static void draw(Graphics2D g, Rectangle2D r, double s) {
    Color c0 = shadowColor;
    //c1 - full opacity color
    Color c1 = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);

    double x0 = r.getMinX();
    double y0 = r.getMinY();
    double x1 = r.getMaxX();
    double y1 = r.getMaxY();
    double w = r.getWidth();
    double h = r.getHeight();

    // Left
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y0), c0,
      new Point2D.Double(x0 - s, y0), c1));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y0, s, h));

    // Right
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
      new Point2D.Double(x1, y0), c0,
      new Point2D.Double(x1 + s, y0), c1));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y0, s, h));

    // Top
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y0), c0,
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y0 - s), c1));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0, y0 - s, w, s));

    // Bottom
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y1), c0,
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y1 + s), c1));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0, y1, w, s));

    float fractions[] = new float[] {
      0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    Color colors[] = new Color[] {
      c0, c1
    };

    // Top Left
    g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
      new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y0 - s, s + s, s + s),
      fractions, colors, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y0 - s, s, s));

    // Top Right
    g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
      new Rectangle2D.Double(x1 - s, y0 - s, s + s, s + s),
      fractions, colors, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y0 - s, s, s));

    // Bottom Left
    g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
      new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y1 - s, s + s, s + s),
      fractions, colors, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y1, s, s));

    // Bottom Right
    g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
      new Rectangle2D.Double(x1 - s, y1 - s, s + s, s + s),
      fractions, colors, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, s, s));
  }

  public static Color getShadowColor() {
    return shadowColor;
  }

  public static void setShadowColor(Color shadowColor) {
    DropShadowPanel.shadowColor = shadowColor;
  }

  public static int getShadowSize() {
    return shadowSize;
  }

  public static void setShadowSize(int shadowSize) {
    DropShadowPanel.shadowSize = shadowSize;
  }

  public static int getShadowDistance() {
    return shadowDistance;
  }

  public static void setShadowDistance(int distance) {
    DropShadowPanel.shadowDistance = distance;
  }
}
```

В Java 6:

[image: Java 6]

В Java 7/8:

[image: Java 7/8]